# webpack output - one asset is bigger than the whole?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

how is it possible that:

- [lodash.merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.merge) is reported by Webpack as having a size of 58.2Kb. the site `cost-of-modules` [is reporting it to be only 11.5kB](http://cost-of-modules.herokuapp.com/?p=lodash.merge@4.6.0)
- the whole bundle is smaller - 49.6kB

please tell me in comments if more information is needed to understand.

```
Version: webpack 2.4.1
Time: 2344ms
   Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
index.js  49.6 kB       0  [emitted]  index
   [0] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
   [2] ./index.js 68 bytes {0} [built]
   [3] ./src/facebook-login.jsx 6.76 kB {0} [built]
   [4] ./src/helpers/helpers.js 1.46 kB {0} [built]
   [5] ./src/spinner.jsx 2.84 kB {0} [built]
   [6] ./src/style/styles.js 688 bytes {0} [built]
   [9] ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"includePaths":["absolute/path/a","absolute/path/b"]}!./src/style/spinner.scss 236 bytes {0} [built]
   //  <----lodash.merge is 58.2kb ---->
  [15] ./~/lodash.merge/index.js 58.2 kB {0} [built]
  [16] ./~/prop-types/factoryWithThrowingShims.js 1.59 kB {0} [built]
  [17] ./~/prop-types/index.js 1.08 kB {0} [built]
  [18] ./~/prop-types/lib/ReactPropTypesSecret.js 436 bytes {0} [built]
  [19] ./~/style-loader/addStyles.js 8.51 kB {0} [built]
  [21] ./src/style/spinner.scss 1.08 kB {0} [built]
  [22] ./src/style/icon.png 1.59 kB {0} [built]
  [24] multi ./index.js 28 bytes {0} [built]
    + 10 hidden modules
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of code or responses. Copy the response and post it here.

Comment: ok done... thought might be easier to spot the lodash with an arrow

Comment: You can highlight those with comments and bold it

Comment: added a comment, but making a comment bold didn't really work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that website is incorrect:

```
$ npm i lodash.merge
...

+ lodash.merge@4.6.0
added 1 package in 0.458s

$ ls -al node_modules/lodash.merge
total 72
drwxrwxr-x 6 robert staff   204 Jun 20 16:00 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 robert staff   102 Jun 20 16:00 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 robert staff  1951 Aug 13  2016 LICENSE
-rw-r--r-- 1 robert staff   446 Aug 13  2016 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 robert staff 58183 Aug 13  2016 index.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 robert staff  1804 Jun 20 16:00 package.json
```

So the size of `index.js` is pretty much what Webpack says it is.

The reason why your bundle is smaller is probably because you're creating a minified bundle. This reduces the size of `index.js` significantly:

```
$ uglifyjs < node_modules/lodash.merge/index.js | wc -c
   21635
```

Comment: you mean that when it states the size of lodash.merge, it's ~58k before the minification, and when it states the overall size of the bundle (~49k) it's after the minification?

Comment: That's correct, yes. I don't think Webpack can return the after-minification sizes of each dependency because minification is performed on the entire bundle and not on the individual dependencies. FWIW, if you want to analyze bundle contents/sizes, I've been using [`webpack-bundle-analyzer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) for the last couple of days, it really provided me with some good insight on where all that bundle space is going.